# "react-scripts test" working on my local, but not on CircleCI

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, continuous-integration, circleci, react-scripts

When I run "npm test" locally, it passes without any issue however when I try to run my tests on CircleCI, I am getting the error

**Too long with no output (exceeded 15m0s): context deadline exceeded**

According to various solutions mentioned I tried :

1. Setting up CI:true
2. Used command *react-scripts test --watchAll=false --maxWorkers=2*

package.json looks like :

```
{
  "name": "task",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "npm": "7.18.1",
    "node": "14.15.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    "@pdftron/webviewer": "^8.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "formik": "^1.5.7",
    "fs-extra": "^10.0.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.16",
    "hotkeys-js": "^3.8.7",
    "html2canvas": "git+https://github.com/PDFTron/html2canvas.git#pdftron-alpha10",
    "intl-tel-input": "^17.0.3",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "json-server": "^0.14.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.41.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "multiselect-react-dropdown": "^1.5.7",
    "npm": "^7.18.1",
    "pusher-js": "^4.4.0",
    "query-string": "^6.8.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-draggable": "^4.4.4",
    "react-dropzone": "^10.1.5",
    "react-icons": "^3.6.1",
    "react-intl-tel-input-v2": "^1.0.8",
    "react-loading-overlay": "^1.0.1",
    "react-maskedinput": "^4.0.1",
    "react-measure": "^2.3.0",
    "react-multi-email": "^0.5.1",
    "react-picky": "^5.3.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-router": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-s3-uploader": "^4.8.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "react-select": "^3.1.1",
    "react-swipeable": "^5.5.1",
    "react-table": "^6.10.0",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.3",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.3",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.10.0",
    "rosie": "^2.0.1",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.6",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --watchAll=false --maxWorkers=2",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "postinstall": "node tools/copy-webviewer-files.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.1.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^3.2.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "react-log": "^4.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.12.0",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.3.1"
  }
}
```

and here is my CircleCI config.yml file

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:14.15.4
        environment:
         CI: true
    resource_class: xlarge
  
    working_directory: ~/project
    steps:
      - checkout
      
      # - restore_cache:
      #     keys:
      #     - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
        
      # - run:
      #     name: Update NPM
      #     command: "sudo npm install -g npm@5"
      - run: npm install
   
      # - save_cache:
      #     paths:
      #       - node_modules
      #       - ~/.npm 
      #       - ~/.cache
      #     key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
      - run:
          name: "What was my custom environment variable?"
          command: echo ${CI}
      - run: 
          name: Run Tests
          no_output_timeout: 15m
          # command: CI=true npm test
          command: npm test
          environment:
            CI: true
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I noticed that `npm test` and `react-scripts test` both spawn child processes, this may have some impact in CI, I was able to get better results calling the react-scripts/test.js directly, along with --runInBand --watchAll=false options. 
`node ./node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/test.js --runInBand --watchAll=false`

Comment: Thanks ! I tested `--runInBand` and it fixed the issue and then read that `--maxWorkers=2` would fix it too with better performances (and it does).